# How to remove Eclipse Context menu"MOVE" from project explorer from my Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

I have a usecase, I have a plugin and I want to remove the 'MOVE' context menu coming from Eclipse in the project explorer. The `ID` for the action which I'm getting from plugin spy is `="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.Move"`. I tried a hack , but it did not work.

```
  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
        <actionProvider
            class="com.dwb.repository.refactoring.ui.refactor.MoveActionProvider"
            id="com.dwb.repository.refactoring.ui.MoveActionExtension"
            overrides="org.eclipse.ui.edit.move"
            priority="highest">
            <enablement>
            <!-- A hack to allways be enabled -->
                <not>
                    <systemTest
                        property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                        value="com.myProjectNature">
                    </systemTest>
                </not>
            </enablement>
        </actionProvider>
    </extension>
```

Is there a better way? Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Why do you want do disable Move? It looks like you should possibly be hooking in to the Eclipse refactoring API.

Comment: Hi,In the project explorer i have added my own command -> refactor-> move for a different perspective in my project. So i need to remove "MOVE".

Comment: There is a lot of code from many plug-in that needs to run when objects are moved. The Eclipse refactoring API deals with this.

Comment: The Move command which i have added extends to thre Eclipse REfactoring API. I use the LTK Framework, so the move actually performs the operation accordingly. But i need to add few more details /conditions for the move of my domain objects. Even in Eclipse plugin , for Java files the Move does not appear. Only Refactor->move.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to define a disabled activity and match this with the menu id you want to suppress.

Note: The activities are shown in `Preferences > General > Capabilities` so the user can enable them again.

Comment: Is there any way to get the Refactor-> Move option from Eclipse? What i found was JDT also adds it as a new Command and handler.

Comment: The `Refactor` menu is added by individual views and editors, so I don't think there is anything that covers all of them.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks I was able to remove the 'Move' context menu from project explorer.

Comment: @greg-449 I can't find these activities in eclipse photon, I need to have the id of the rename context menu of project explorer. How can I get that id?